# Submit multiple forms with one Submit All button in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form in Angular setup like the following.

Users can make changes and submit one at a time and it works as expected but I'd like to add a "Submit All" that would submit each item one at a time as though the user were pressing the submit button for each. Im a little stumped on the best way to do this. As of right now I cannot submit them as a batch due to API constraints. I would also like to keep jQuery out of the equation.

My first thought is to create a new object that contains the info for each item and then loop over it and submit that way. I am unsure how to set this up in my controller.

```
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Kids</th>
        <th></th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="pending-item animate-repeat"
            data-ng-repeat="user in Users"
            data-ng-form="userForm"
            role="form"
            data-ng-submit="submitUser(user, userDetails)"
            novalidate>
          <td class="img-container">
            <img data-ng-src="{{user['image']['url']}}"
              alt="{{user['image']['alt'] || ' '}}"
              class="img-responsive"   >
          </td>
          <td class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="user-info">
              <p class="user-name">
                {{user['name']}}
              </p>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
              <span class="input-group-addon">Age</span>
              <input type="number" min="0"
                    name="age"
                    class="form-control age"
                    data-ng-init="userDetails.age = user['age']"
                    data-ng-model="userDetails.age"
                    required>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
              <input type="number" min="0" step="1"
                    name="kids"
                    class="form-control kids"
                    data-ng-disabled="user['kids'] === true"
                    data-ng-pattern="/^\d+$/"
                    data-ng-init="userDetails.kidsCount = user['kids']['quantity']"
                    data-ng-model="userDetails.kidsCount"
                    required>
              <div class="input-group-addon"># of kids</div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="btn-group btn-col">
              <button type="submit"
                      class="btn btn-success btn-sm"
                      data-ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid || userDetails.working"
                      data-ng-click="submitUser(user, userDetails)">
                  Submit
                </span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button ng-click="submitAllUsers()">Submit All Users</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: it looks like you are missing some code? the stuff above and below the `<td>` isn't attached to an element.

Comment: By the way, if your button is inside of the form tags, you won't need an ng-click and a ng-submit. I suggest just having the ng-submit to call submitItem()

Comment: Did you try to wrap the two forms inside a parent form and use actually two submits? one for each child form and a global one for the parent

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create a object in your controller, say `$scope.formData={}`, and then bind it with your elements using `ng-model` or `data-ng-model` and then on button click pass this object in your controller and do the required stuff.

Comment: How would I bind  "data-ng-model="itemDetails.price" to $scope.formData?

      $scope.formData{
        price: itemDetails.price
      }

Something like that?

Comment: No,you dont have to bind it to some other object.. use formData or itemDetails as object and then pass that object on your click event....

Comment: I updated my example to give a bit more detail.

So I would pass userDetails with the submitAllUsers.

     <button ng-click="submitAllUsers(userDetails)">Submit All Users</button>

Comment: Thanks. I must be doing something wrong because when I pass productDetails with submitAllUsers I get undefined. Im wondering if ng-init is causing issues.

Comment: it's userDetails ryt?

Comment: Yes. Sorry my original example was itemDetails.
If I setup $scope.userDetails = {}; at the top of my controller and then pass userDetails it gives me only the last userDetails and sets every form value the same in the view.

Comment: yes,dat's maybe because,if you are using the same object property name in your last input tag,it will overwitten and you will get the last result.In your case why not use an array of objects,if the property name is going to be the same.,and then pass the array object on your button click.